# Query to join 1 table with 2 overlapped tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables with identical columns. They have records that are the same and records that are different.

```
CREATE TABLE APP (
    APPID int NOT NULL,
    APPName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE HW_SERVER1 (
    APPID int NOT NULL,
    MachineName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    LocationCd varchar(255),
    CONSTRAINT PK_HW PRIMARY KEY (APPID, MachineName)
);

CREATE TABLE HW_SERVER2 (
    APPID int NOT NULL,
    MachineName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    LocationCd varchar(255),
    CONSTRAINT PK_HW PRIMARY KEY (APPID, MachineName)
);
```

### HW_SERVER1

| APPID | MachineName | LocationCd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | m1 | a1 |
| 1 | m2 | a2 |
| 2 | m1 | a1 |
| 2 | m3 | a3 |
| 3 | m5 | a2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

### HW_SERVER2

| APPID | MachineName | LocationCd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | m1 | a1 |
| 2 | m6 | a6 |
| 2 | m7 | a2 |
| 2 | m5 | a2 |
| 3 | m5 | a2 |
| 5 | m8 | a5 |
| 6 | m2 | a2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Each MachineName has a unique LocationCd. What I need is a result set that includes all distinct LocationCd for all APPID.

### Result Set

| APPID | LocationCd |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 |
| 1 | a2 |
| 2 | a1 |
| 2 | a2 |
| 2 | a3 |
| 2 | a6 |
| 3 | a2 |
| 5 | a5 |
| 6 | a2 |

A result set that includes MachineName is useful as well, I just have to remove the duplicate APPID/LocationCd combinations.

Thanks for any feedback or suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want `union` (not `union all` because you want to remove duplicates):

```
select APPID, LocationCd
from hw_server1
union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select APPID, LocationCd
from hw_server2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Everyone was quick to jump on the easy answer to use `UNION` to remove dupes (as opposed to `UNION ALL`) but missed your mention that having MachineName column would be useful to you as well. Please see this answer which gives you the distinct result set with all 3 columns:

```
WITH CTE_UniqueLocationCd AS
(
    SELECT APPID, LocationCd
    FROM HW_SERVER1

    UNION -- Removes dupes

    SELECT APPID, LocationCd
    FROM HW_SERVER2
),
CTE_UniqueMachineName AS
(
    SELECT APPID, MachineName
    FROM HW_SERVER1

    UNION -- Removes dupes

    SELECT APPID, MachineName
    FROM HW_SERVER2
)

SELECT DISTINCT -- Final removal of dupes that result from the many-to-many join on APPID
    ULC.APPID, UMN.MachineName, ULC.LocationCd
FROM CTE_UniqueLocationCd AS ULC
INNER JOIN CTE_UniqueMachineName AS UMN
    ON ULC.APPID = UMN.APPID
```

Good question to learn the difference between `UNION ALL` and `UNION`, you have my upvote.

Comment: this is such a neat way to filter out dups!

Comment: @etopia No prob! If you have any questions, feel free and I'll do my best to answer them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union`

```
select appid, locationcd from HW_SERVER1
union 
select appid, locationcd from HW_SERVER2
```

Answer (score 1):

A union query would seem to be the most straightforward approach here:

```sql
SELECT a.APPID, hw.LocationCd
FROM APP a INNER JOIN HW_SERVER1 hw ON hw.APPID = a.APPID
UNION
SELECT a.APPID, hw.LocationCd
FROM APP a INNER JOIN HW_SERVER2 hw ON hw.APPID = a.APPID;
```

Note: I perform the joins above to ensure that we only report on apps which appear in the `APP` table proper.

Answer (score 1):

You could join the 2 tables and take a distinct set.

```
SELECT DISTINCT APPID, LocationCd
FROM
(
  SELECT APPID, LocationCd
  FROM HW_SERVER1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT APPID, LocationCd
  FROM HW_SERVER2
)
```

Comment: Of course using straight `union` removes the need for `distinct`.